# Integral of second modified Bessel function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

I would like to compute the integral of the second modified Bessel function which has the following form
$$
\int^{\infty}_{\epsilon}{dz \;z^a K_{\nu}(z)}
$$

where I have some power of $z$ multiplied by the function and later I would like to take the limit of $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. I am aware that this is some kind of hypergeometric function but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43#E19) we know
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\alpha} K_\nu(t)\, \mathrm{d}t = 2^{\alpha -1} \Gamma\left( \frac{\alpha + \nu +1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left( \frac{\alpha - \nu +1}{2}\right) \qquad \text{for} \quad \lvert\Re(\nu)\rvert< \Re(\alpha)+1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Provided $a \ge\nu\ge 0$, Maple says
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty }\!{z}^{a}{{\rm K}_{\nu}\left(z\right)}
\,{\rm d}z =
{\frac {{2}^{a-1}{\pi}^{2}}{\Gamma \left( 1/2-\nu/2-a/2 \right) \Gamma
 \left( \nu/2-a/2+1/2 \right)  \left(  \cos^2 \left( \pi\,a
 /2\right)+ \cos^2 \left( \pi\,\nu/2 \right) 
 -1 \right) }}
$$

In case you really need it, here it is without the limit:

`(-sin(Pi*nu)*epsilon^(-nu+a+1)*cos(1/2*Pi*(-nu+a))*cos(1/2*Pi*(nu+a))*GAMMA(1/2-1/2 *nu-1/2*a)*GAMMA(1/2*nu-1/2*a+1/2)*nu*GAMMA(nu)^2*2^(-1+nu)*(nu+a+1)*hypergeom( [-1/2*nu+1/2*a+1/2],[1-nu, 3/2-1/2*nu+1/2*a],1/4*epsilon^2)+(epsilon^(nu+a+1)*cos(1/2* Pi*(-nu+a))*cos(1/2*Pi*(nu+a))*GAMMA(1/2-1/2*nu-1/2*a)*GAMMA(1/2*nu-1/2*a+1/2)* 2^(-nu-1)*(-nu+a+1)*hypergeom([1/2*nu+1/2*a+1/2],[nu+1, 3/2+1/2*nu+1/2*a],1/4* epsilon^2)+nu*GAMMA(nu)*sin(Pi*nu)*Pi*((a^2-nu^2+1)*2^(a-1)+a*2^a))*Pi)/cos(1/2*Pi* (nu+a))/cos(1/2*Pi*(-nu+a))/(-nu+a+1)/GAMMA(1/2-1/2*nu-1/2*a)/GAMMA(1/2*nu-1/2* a+1/2)/(nu+a+1)/sin(Pi*nu)/GAMMA(nu)/nu`

Comment: The formula is true under the weaker condition $|\Re (\nu)|<\Re (a)+1$. This can be seen by looking at the [limiting form](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.30.i) of the $K$ Bessel function at $0+$. There is no issue with the convergence of the integral at infinity. Also the formula can be simplified greatly as shown in the answer by Robert Lee.

Comment: Interesting.  The two answers are related by the duplication formula for $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:**

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{s-1}K_{\nu}(t)dt=2^{s-2}\,\,\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{\nu}{2} \right)\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}-\frac{\nu}{2} \right)$$

---

Recall the integral [representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E9):

$$K_{\nu}(x)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x \cosh t} \cosh (\nu t) dt$$

Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1 }\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x \cosh t} \cosh (\nu t) dt\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cosh (\nu t) \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x \cosh t}x^{s-1 }  dx\,dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cosh (\nu t)\cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(s\right)}{\left(  \cosh t\right)^{s}} dt\\
&=\Gamma\left(s\right)\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh (\nu t)}{  \cosh ^{s}(t)} dt\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(s\right)}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\nu t}+e^{-\nu t}}{  \cosh ^{s}(t)} dt\\
&=2^{s-1}\Gamma\left(s\right)\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\nu t}+e^{-\nu t}}{ \left( e^t+e^{-t} \right)^{s}} dt\\
&=2^{s-1}\Gamma\left(s\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st}}{e^{-st}}\cdot \frac{e^{\nu t}+e^{-\nu t}}{ \left( e^t+e^{-t} \right)^{s}} dt\\
&=2^{s-1}\Gamma\left(s\right)\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(s-\nu) t}+e^{-(\nu+s) t}}{ \left( 1+e^{-2t} \right)^{s}} dt\\
&=2^{s-2}\Gamma\left(s\right)\int_{0}^1\frac{w^{\frac{(s-\nu)}{2}-1 }+w^{\frac{(\nu+s)}{2}-1 }}{ \left( 1+w \right)^{s}} \, dw &\left(e^{-2t}=w\right)\\
&=2^{s-2}\Gamma\left(s\right)\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{\nu}{2} \right)\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}-\frac{\nu}{2} \right)}{\Gamma\left(s \right)} \qquad \blacksquare
\end{aligned}
$$

Where in the last line we used the Beta function (see below)

---

#### Appendix

$$\int_0^{1}\frac{t^{x-1}+t^{y-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt=\frac{\Gamma\left(x \right)\Gamma\left(y \right)}{\Gamma\left(x+y \right)}$$

Proof:

Recall the [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas) for the Beta function

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt=\frac{\Gamma\left(x \right)\Gamma\left(y \right)}{\Gamma\left(x+y \right)}$$

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt&=\int_0^{1}\frac{t^{x-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt\\
&=\int_0^{1}\frac{t^{x-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt+\int_1^{0}\frac{w^{1-x}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{w} \right)^{x+y}}\frac{-dw}{w^2}\\
&=\int_0^{1}\frac{t^{x-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt+\int_0^{1}\frac{w^{1-x}w^{x+y}w^{-2}}{\left(1+w \right)^{x+y}}dw\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt\\
&=\int_0^{1}\frac{t^{x-1}+t^{y-1}}{\left(1+t \right)^{x+y}}dt
\end{aligned}
$$